# Cannot open source file: '../common/maskApi.c' in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://pythonprogramming.net/training-custom-objects-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/?completed=/creating-tfrecord-files-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/) on training a custom object detector using TensorFlow. When I run the command: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` I get the error below. I believe it's an issue with `pycocotools` but I'm not entirely sure. Can anyone point me in the direction of solving this error?

```
   C:\Users\<Username>\models\research\object_detection>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
    running build_ext
    skipping 'pycocotools\_mask.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I../common "-IC:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include" "-IC:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tc../common/maskApi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\../common/maskApi.obj gcc
    cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'gcc', object file assumed
    cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'gcc' ignored
    maskApi.c
    c1: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '../common/maskApi.c': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```